# Spring inline-script

Tags: java, spring

Добрый день. Изучаю спринг по книге spring in action. Возникла проблема при внедрении инлайн скрипта. Делаю все как написано в книге, но компилироваться отказывается. Судя по ошибкам проблема в пространстве имен, но, вроде, все зависимости добавлены - в чем причина не могу понять. Если удалить из контекста определение скрипта и вызов метода интерфейса из кода - то все компилируется, класс создается нормально. Заранее благодарен за помощь.
pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nomatter.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

файл конфигурации контекста:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd">
    <bean name="a_class" class="Aimpl">
        <property name="a" ref="a_interface"/>
    </bean>
    <lang:bsh id="a_interface" script-interfaces="A">
        <lang:inline-script>
            <![CDATA[
               void execute(){
                  System.out.println("created from script");
               }]]>
        </lang:inline-script>
    </lang:bsh>
</beans>
```

класс контроллер:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        A a = (A)context.getBean("a_class");
        a.execute();
    }
}
```

класс А:

```
public class Aimpl{
    private A a;
    public void setA(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void echo(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " created");
        a.execute();
    }
}
```

интерфейс:

```
public interface A {
    void execute();
}
```

код ошибок:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49993:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/stroiker/IdeaProjects/test-spring/target/classes:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/stroiker/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar Main
objc[650]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10b96e4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10d1f14e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
июл 14, 2017 1:24:08 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2ef1e4fa: startup date [Fri Jul 14 13:24:08 YEKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
июл 14, 2017 1:24:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [config.xml]
июл 14, 2017 1:24:09 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a_class' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'a_interface' while setting bean property 'a'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a_interface': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptFactory.a_interface': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.scripting.bsh.BshScriptFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a_class' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'a_interface' while setting bean property 'a'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a_interface': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptFactory.a_interface': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.scripting.bsh.BshScriptFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a_interface': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptFactory.a_interface': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.scripting.bsh.BshScriptFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptFactory.a_interface': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.scripting.bsh.BshScriptFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.scripting.support.ScriptFactoryPostProcessor.prepareScriptBeans(ScriptFactoryPostProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.scripting.support.ScriptFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(ScriptFactoryPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:154)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.EvalError
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
    <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
    <version>2.0b5</version>
</dependency>
```

Исправьте код

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
    Aimpl a = (Aimpl) context.getBean("a_class");
    a.echo();
}
```

И все будет работать.

Comment: Про кривой каст уже понял, про зависимость не знал. Спасибо.